# Changing default Cartthrob language files

Tags: cartthrob

What is the best way to alter some of the default user feedback messages stored in the language files? I can obviously edit directly the language file in question but that would get overwritten on every upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You can move cartthrob lang files into

system > expressionengine > language > english (or other language folder)

If you upload again, the CT lang files WILL override those found in the EE language folder, but at least will not overwrite them.

Comment: So, as a final step one would then have to delete the files in system > expressionengine > third_party > cartthrob > language > english again to get rid of the override?